# Publishing a scientific article without being a student or a researcher

Tags: research-process, authorship, productivity, independent-researcher

From what I got to see during my research internship, research master's students, PhD students and researchers, when they do some decent research work or project, they sometimes send a scientific article to get published (after a selection process). In the case of students, whether it be master's or PhD students, there are always mentors or advisers that direct their work and join their names to theirs in the published paper.

I would like to know whether it is possible for anyone (someone who is neither a student nor a research, and who is not even an employed person) who does a research or even an implementation-driven work (such as building an application in the case of computer engineering) to submit a paper for publication and get it published.

Of course I bear in mind that in order to gain some recognition and to be selected for publication, the work should contribute with some knowledge to the scientific community.

If the answer is yes, how to proceed?

Comment: In civil engineering, I have seen independent researchers who contribute to industry-based researches and publish good papers. Even some interdisciplinary researchers for instance developers of computer programs with aim to solve civil engineering problems. Also some of the researchers have literature review papers. However, I think the research work for such independent researchers is so more difficult. And, your question is so dependent on the major, because doing independent research in some majors is almost impossible while in some others, it is easier indeed.

Comment: Actually I am interested in the major of computer engineering.

Comment: You proceed in the same way a student or professional researcher would: write a paper and submit it somewhere.

Comment: outside of the research world, are there any magazines that publish articles illustrating engineering projects (like as I said, new software built by a developper, and such) submitted to them by people who did those projects?

Comment: Here is a list of journals that will publish articles that you write about your software that you think would be interesting to scientists.
http://www.software.ac.uk/resources/guides/which-journals-should-i-publish-my-software